# What's the equivalent of .sample in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, methods, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a small Chrome extension soon to be released, however in this extension I must take a random item from an array and display it on the screen. In the past, I've worked with a lot of Ruby code, and remember the method '.sample' which displays a random item from an array on the screen.

Example (in Ruby):

```
farm_animals = ['cow', 'chicken', 'pig', 'horse']
puts farm_animals.sample
```

The output could end up being something like...

```
>> cow
```

Is there an equivalent to this handy array method in Javascript? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ruby and looking for `.sample` in google didn't turn up anything. Can you point me in a direction where I can see what sample does and I can likely help you out

Comment: @Seth Here's the Rubydocs Array class & methods. THe .sample method is on the side panel in alphabetical order, and I've got the quick link to the .sample area. http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sample

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
var farm_animals = ['cow', 'chicken', 'pig', 'horse']
alert(farm_animals[Math.floor ( Math.random() * farm_animals.length )])
```

or as a function:

```
function sample(array) {
  return array[Math.floor ( Math.random() * array.length )]
}

console.log(sample(farm_animals))
```

Comment: You forgot a `return` before the `array[...]`, it works from there, thanks!

Comment: Heh, it takes getting used to. You could add some semicolons too. :-P

Comment: are they really required? ruby again! I have witten quite a lot of javascript and rarely need them

Comment: In your case the content of the function can be without one, since at the last line (in your case the first line) of functions you can go without one and it'll work. However the `console.log` should have one. Sometimes I start to think Ruby does too much for you. :-P

Answer (score 3):

If you're not averse to hacking built-in object prototypes:

```
Array.prototype.sample = function() {
  return this[~~(Math.random() * this.length)];
}
```

Then

```
var samp = ["hello", "friendly", "world"].sample();
```

gives you a random element.

A lot — many, most — people would say that such a not-so-useful function would not be worth the sin of polluting a built-in prototype like that. Follow your bliss.

Comment: @Vigrond well yes but there are interoperability ramifications to modifying the prototype objects of the built-in classes.

Comment: Can you please explain the double bitwise not? Nevermind, I see now that you're using it as a shorthand for Math.floor